# Vue.js Input value gets deleted on first char only

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Based on the official example [Custom Input Component example:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app" >
  <div :class="{'has-value' : hasValue}">
    <input type="text"
      ref="input"
      v-bind:value="value"
      @input="onInput" >
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      hasValue: false
      }
  },
  props: ['value'],
  methods:{
  onInput: function(){
    val= this.$refs.input.value
      if(val && val.length > 0){
        this.hasValue = true
      } else {
        this.hasValue = false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delcon/jwok2jsx/) to play

**Expected:**
Dynamically set `hasValue` data for input and bind a Css Class to this data

**Unexpected:**
Only after initialization and typing the first Character, the typed character gets deleted from the input. Press JS-Fiddle->Run to see it again.

After first character everything works as expected.

If I remove `v-bind:value="value"` or comment `\\this.hasValue = true` it works as expected. Binding value prop is recommended for custom Input component.

Is this intended and why? Or is this a bug I should report?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is expected behaviour:

- When the first character is inserted, `hasValue` is changed from `false` to `true`, causing the component to re-render
- During re-render, Vue sees that the input has a value (the character you just typed in), but the property you have bound to it (the `value` prop) is empty.
- Therefore, Vue updates the input to match the bound prop - and thus, it empties the input.
- After that, `hasValue` doesn't change anymore, so there's no re-rendering happening, and thus, Vue doesn't reset the input field's value anymore.

#### So how to fix this?

First you have to understand that Vue is data-driven - the data determines the HTML, not the other way around. So if you want your input to have a value, you have to reflect that value in the property bound to it.

This would be trivial if you worked with a local data property:

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/jwok2jsx/2/

But since you used a prop, and I assume you want to continue using it, the sittuation is a bit different - Vue follows a pattern of "data down - events up". You can't change props from within a child, you have to tell the *parent* from which you got it that you want to change it with an event. The responsibility to change it would be the parent's. Here's your example with a proper parent-child relationship:

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/jwok2jsx/4/

Comment: ... causing the component to re-render was the key for me. Thanks for your in depth explanation.

Comment: Causing the component to re-render was the key for me as well. If it helps anyone the idea I had was to use something like ex:

this.$el.querySelector('input').classList[hasValue]('has-value') where hasValue will be set before ex:

const hasValue = Boolean(event.target.value) ? 'add' : 'remove'
 
This would set the class directly and avoid render

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that when you modified `hasValue`, Vue re-renders the component (to apply the `has-value` class to the div) which causes the `v-bind:value` to be re-evaluated. `value` is a prop which is unassigned and never changes, so the value of the input element gets cleared.

You really should use `v-model` on the input element and control `has-value` based on the `value` in the model, rather than interacting directly with the DOM. (You won't be able to use `v-model` with `value` though since `value` is a prop and cannot be assigned from within the component.)

I'm also guessing you want to make a custom input component which applies a certain style when it has a value. Try this:

```js
Vue.component('my-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `<input class="my-input" :class="{ 'has-value': value }" type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: '',
  },
});
```

```css
.my-input.has-value {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-input v-model="value"></my-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: ''
  },
  computed: {
    hasValue () {
      return this.input.length ? true : false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.has-value {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div :class="{'has-value' : hasValue}">
    <input type="text" v-model="input">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```